# React PropTypes do not work properly when defining propTypes with spread (...) operator

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I'm trying to have single PropTypes definition to reuse it in several components, and have issues with that. I define the static propTypes in separate class and then import it as module. Say, I have React component of a view:

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ExampleType from './example-type.js';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    ...ExampleType.propTypes,  // <--- note here, that's how I'm trying to make it work
    
    // and the line below duplicates same field from ExampleType.propTypes, 
    // this is needed because otherwise Linter throws an error
    // that PropTypes is defined, but never used:
    instanceName: PropTypes.string
  }
  
  static defaultProps = {
    ...ExampleType.defaultProps
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{this.props.instanceName}</h3>
        <p>
          {this.props.instanceValue}
        </p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

example-type.js is that:

```html
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class ExampleType {
  static propTypes = {
    instanceName: PropTypes.string,
    instanceValue: PropTypes.string
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    instanceName: '',
    instanceValue: ''
  }
}

export default ExampleType;
```

And doing this way, PropTypes check does not happen. If I change defaultProps definition to that without spread operator:

```html
  static propTypes = {
    // ...ExampleType.propTypes,     // and now without spread ...
    instanceName: PropTypes.string,
    instanceValue: PropTypes.string
  }
```

Than it works as expected.

Well, I know that reusing of single property types definition is available in different ways like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/37720537/2335174 , but I'm curios why my variant with spread operator does not work. MyComponent.propTypes object looks the same in debugger in both cases, with and without spread.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work for me, see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/jlll2zm6xv

Have you included the [transform-object-rest-spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/) plugin in your Babel setup?

Comment: Hi @Will Hawker, thank you for sandbox, it really works there. But in my case this does not work by some reason. Looks like worth examine project settings.

Comment: Looks like I just misunderstood the concept of PropTypes. transform-object-rest-spread did the magic.