# How can I centralize proptypes which are not the same

Tags: reactjs, reusability, react-proptypes, centralized

I want to centralize proptypes that might contain different properties and be or not required. As an example:

Component A has:

```
roomData: PropTypes.shape({
  roomId: PropTypes.number,
  roomType: PropTypes.string,
}).isRequired,
```

while Component B has:

```
roomData: PropTypes.shape({
  roomId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
  roomType: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  game: PropTypes.shape({
    gameId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    drawDescription: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  }).isRequired,
}),
```

If both are COMPLETELY the same, I know how to do it. The problem is about them being different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS: How can I have a more modular use of prop types & shapes for objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912334/reactjs-how-can-i-have-a-more-modular-use-of-prop-types-shapes-for-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Since `PropTypes.shape` expect a plain JS object, you can create an external file where you keep your shapes and use/combine them whenever you need it.

It'd be something like `utils/propTypesShapes.js`:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
export const transformToRequired = (shape) => {
  return Object.keys(shape).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = shape[curr].isRequired;
    return acc;
  }, {})
}
export const roomDataBaseShape = {
  roomId: PropTypes.number,
  roomType: PropTypes.string,
}
```

Then in your components:

```
import { roomDataBaseShape, transformToRequired } from 'propTypes/shapes'
ComponentA.propTypes = {
  roomData: PropTypes.shape(roomDataBaseShape).isRequired
}

ComponentB.propTypes = {
  roomData: PropTypes.shape({
    ...transformToRequired(roomDataBaseShape),
    game: PropTypes.shape({
      gameId: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
      drawDescription: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  })
}
```